# Migration from Android to Flutter implications

Tags: flutter

I have taken time to to see that I get my hands on flutter ever since I started to hear of it from my fellow android developers. It has not been easy am glad am getting somewhere in terms of progress of earning flutter. I have began to rewrite one of my android project in flutter. However my greatest concern is that if I rewrite my android project in flutter and use the package name i used in the other project. Am using `sqlite` database in my project and it has been passed on from version to version as I have been updating my app and users like it that. However am not very sure if the migrating my project to flutter affect the users who were using my earlier application loose their data?

I need someone to enlighten me on how to handle such an issue if its not possible to maintain what was in my android project in terms of database. Or rather what options are available.

Answer (score 0):

Play store cares about your apk, as long as your source code uses the same sql-lite cache, should be ok. You can easily test such scenario on the same emulator for instance.